# How to populate dependent dropdowns in angular 7 dynamic forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a dynamic form that has more than one dropdown and one of dropdown dependent another. The problem is that I couldn't populate the dependent dropdown.

```
jobDepartmentDropdownOnChange(e: any) {
    this.personnelRecruitmentInfoService.getAllByJobDepartmentId(e.value).subscribe(
      res => {
        if (res.code === ResponseCode.success) {
          res.dataList.map(item => {
            this.personnels.push({
              value: item.personnel.id.toString(),
              label: item.personnel.dataValue
            });
          });

          if (this.formComponent !== undefined) {
            this.formComponent.form.controls['personnelId'].patchValue(this.personnels);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

```
const personnelDropdown = new InputDropdown({
  key: 'personnelId',
  label: '',
  options: this.personnels,
  value: '',
  disabled: true,
  required: false,
  multiple: true,
  order: 20
});
```

```
public personnels: any[] = [];
```

```
const jobDepartmentDropdown = new InputDropdown({
  key: 'jobDepartmentId',
  label: '',
  options: this.jobDepartments,
  value: '',
  onChange: this.jobDepartmentDropdownOnChange.bind(this),
  disabled: true,
  required: false,
  multiple: true,
  order: 19
});
```

```
export class InputDropdown extends InputBase<string> {
  controlType = 'dropdown';
  options: { value: string, label: string }[] = [];
  showSelect = false;
  multiple = false;

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
    this.options = options['options'] || [];
    this.showSelect = options['showSelect'] || false;
    this.multiple = options['multiple'] || false;
  }
}
```

How can I populate `personnelId` dropdown according to the previous dropdown?

Comment: I think you need change personnelDropdown.options in your subscribe function, (or pehafs is enought define "personnels" **before** "personnelDropdown" but I'm not sure about this last)

Comment: `personnels` already defined before `personnelDropdown`.

Answer (score 0):

You would be way better of using a subject for your personnels over triggering angulars change detection cycle way too often performance wise. But if you simply wonder why your solution doesn't work regardless of performance, you're pushing elements in your personnels object not actually changing the reference held by this.personnels. This means the angular change detection won't be triggered. If you do want to trigger the change detection, alter your "push" like this:

```
jobDepartmentDropdownOnChange(e: any) {
    this.personnelRecruitmentInfoService.getAllByJobDepartmentId(e.value).subscribe(
      res => {
        if (res.code === ResponseCode.success) {
          res.dataList.map(item => {
            // Use the spread operator to create a new array hence 
            // updating the reference in the object angular detects changes upon.
            this.personnels = [...this.personnels, {
              value: item.personnel.id.toString(),
              label: item.personnel.dataValue
            }];
          });

          if (this.formComponent !== undefined) {
            this.formComponent.form.controls['personnelId'].patchValue(this.personnels);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: It is not working as you said. Still `personnelId` dropdown doesn't populated.

Comment: What does your ```InputDropdown``` class look like?

Comment: That doesn't answer what the ```InputDropdown``` class looks like. I fear the thing only sets the options on its template at the OnInit which means it in essence cannot be changed without rerendering the whole dropdown.

Comment: That patchvalue ain't gonna work. It doesn't set the options, it sets the current value. To an array...

Comment: I am calling `bind` function to call this. Is it problem?

Comment: No, that should be fine. You could simply create a new function if you prefer, as in ```e => this. jobDepartmentDropdownOnChange(e)```

Comment: No luck again. What is the result of this problem?

Comment: If the InputDropDown is some component that gets rendered and uses the @Input data on OnInit, it will only use the data provided when the dropdown is first rendered and never update the options. That being the issue would be my best guess. To be sure, you'd have to share your full component and template I'd say.

Comment: I added `InputDropdown`.

Comment: Yeah, which copies some values. I'm sorry, but I don't think anyone can figure this out without some stackblitz example.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
const jobDepartmentDropdown = new InputDropdown({
  key: 'jobDepartmentId',
  label: '',
  options: this.jobDepartments,
  value: '',
  onChange: this.jobDepartmentDropdownOnChange.bind(this),
  disabled: true,
  required: false,
  multiple: true,
  order: 19
});
```

```
((this.inputs as InputBase<any>[]).find(i => i.key === 'personnelId') as InputDropdown).options = options;
```